# How to use a boolean switch to update a graph in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm new in Dash. I'm trying to use a `daq.BooleanSwitch()` like an input to callback a graph. I can display a message but I have troubles with the graph.

Does anyone have any advice that can help me?

```py
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_daq as daq
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Here we go"),

    daq.BooleanSwitch(id='my_pb', on=False,color="red"),
    
    html.Div(id='power-button-result-1'),
    
    dcc.Graph(id="plot")

])

@app.callback(
    Output('power-button-result-1', 'children'),
    Input('my_pb', 'on')
)
def update_output(on):
    x = '{}'.format(on)
    if x == "True":
        return "Hi Iḿ using DASH"

@app.callback(
    Output('plot', 'figure'),
    Input('my_pb', 'on')
)
    
def figura(on):
    x = '{}'.format(on)
    if x == "True":
        # fig1 = Code to do a nice plot 
        return fig1

if __name__ == "__main__":             
    app.run_server(port = 1895)
```

My DASH output look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at your code, and a couple changes were necessary:

```py
import dash
import dash_daq as daq

from dash import dcc
from dash import html

from dash.dependencies import Input
from dash.dependencies import Output


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Here we go"),
        daq.BooleanSwitch(id="my_pb", on=False, color="red"),
        html.Div(id="power-button-result-1"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("power-button-result-1", "children"),
    Input("my_pb", "on"),
)
def update_output(on):
    x = "{}".format(on)
    if x == "True":
        return [dcc.Graph(id="plot")]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

You were super close - I think you only need one callback. Here, you can see the boolean switch now toggles the display (or not) of the `dcc.Graph` object. Is this what you were looking for?

[image]

### ↓ (toggle the switch)

[image]

If you want the graph to already be displayed, and then updated upon toggling, here's a slightly modified expanded version of same code above to do that:

```py
import dash
import dash_daq as daq

from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash import no_update

from dash.dependencies import Input
from dash.dependencies import Output

import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Here we go"),
        daq.BooleanSwitch(id="my_pb", on=False, color="red"),
        html.Div(
            [dcc.Graph(id="plot")], id="power-button-result-1"
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("power-button-result-1", "children"),
    Input("my_pb", "on"),
)
def update_output(on):
    df = px.data.iris()
    if on:
        fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
        return [dcc.Graph(figure=fig)]
    else:
        fig = px.scatter()
        return [dcc.Graph(figure=fig)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: before toggle]
[image: after toggle]

There - that's much better, hopefully helpful?

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful : )
Thanks for using examples

Comment: Yep I tried that but apparently  i need more reputation. Sorry

Comment: Yep, I will back, i promise

Comment: I do it, thanks John